# Unable to click element XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

This is the element I'm trying to reach:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
  <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button style="background-color: rgb(218, 218, 218);" aria-disabled="false" role="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button">
        <span style="background-color: transparent;" class="ui-button-text">OK</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath=(//span[contains(@class,'ui-button-text')][contains(text(),'OK')]))")).Click();
```

I used the find element feature of the Selenium IDE using the xpath and it can find the element.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `xpath=` part inside the expression:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'ui-button-text')][contains(text(),'OK')])")).Click();
```

Also, I think you can stop using `contains()` and check the complete `class` and `text()` values:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class = 'ui-button-text' and . = 'OK'])")).Click();
```

Here the `.` refers to the element's text.

Comment: Although, necessary caveat, if the class might contain more classes inside, you will have to use contains().

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is to use this xpath:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("///div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button/span")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the accurate solution:
*You can use this:*

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/descendant::span[@class='ui-button-text' and contains(text(),'OK')]/parent::button")
```

Comment: the post was from 2 years ago, I think they figured it out by now or re-wrote the app. :)